# How do I view table data, fetched by linq to sql with table join?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How i can do view for such code, if i have join? in asp.net mvc on c# language

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var routeDetails = (from rd in db.Route 
                                join rdd in db.RouteDetail
                                on rd.RouteId equals rdd.RouteId 
                                where rd.RouteId == id 
                                select new
                                        {
                                            RouteId = rd.RouteId,
                                            Name = rd.Name,
                                            Station = rdd.Station,
                                            TimeArrival = rdd.TimeArrival,
                                            TimeDeparture = rdd.TimeDeparture
                                        }).First();
            return View(routeDetails);
        }
```

I can do view for one table without join, but how it will be with join?
here is how i do it without join for edit action:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TrainShedule.Models.Route>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Edit</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>Название маршрута:
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)%>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    <div>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous type for your `routeDetails` variable. If you want a strongly-typed view, you can define a new model class (`RouteRouteDetail` or similar) that contains the properties you want from both tables, and select instances of that type rather than selecting anonymous type instances using the `new {}` syntax.

Comment: I didn't understand, could you explain more detaily?

Comment: ok, i do this, thank you. Now i have more one question: how i can view  with such include Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<TrainShedule.Models.RouteDetailsAndRoute>>"    foreach - for list, and simple html.encode - for one item

Comment: <% var oneitem = Model.ElementAt(0); %>
                <%= Html.Encode(oneitem.RouteId)%>    i have done this for upper question, but if it is more effective answer please give it'